# set value of input vield without showing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i click on span remove address it removes it from ui but not from the list and the printed value of `removeItem` is an empty string `""`.
and how can i pass the stringList to input `value=""` with id `clientAdd` without showing it on the input .

```js
var stringList = [];
$("#clientAdd").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" + "<span class='removeAddress'>" + '+' + "</span>" + this.value + "</a>");
    stringList.push(this.value);
    this.value = "";
    console.log(stringList);
    $(document).on("click", ".removeAddress", function() {
      var removeItem = $(this).parent().parent().val();
      console.log(removeItem);
      stringList.splice($.inArray(removeItem, stringList), 1);
      $(this).parent().remove();

      console.log(stringList);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <label>Address *</label>
      <div class="target"></div>
      <input type="text" id="clientAdd" name="address" value="" class="form-control required">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can hide whole input or you can use input type="hidden". Usually you have one input displayed for humans as a event trigger and input hidden for the value which is processed on the server side

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Its parent text not a `parent of parent` .so you need get the text value of the parent use with `$(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()` .It will get the parent text only .[`end() documentation`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiX3r_1zabUAhXGso8KHaM5A3cQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fend%2F&usg=AFQjCNE6CFHzLOezHscew28ZVI1Wz5avvw&sig2=oFm1nU3kXZiIGw5DdgUi3g)
2. After removing clicked element .you are create the array  using remaining `removeddress` via map function

```js
var stringList = [];
$("#clientAdd").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" + "<span class='removeAddress'>" + '+' + "</span>" + this.value + "</a><br>");
    stringList.push(this.value);
    this.value = "";
    console.log(stringList);
    $(document).on("click", ".removeAddress", function() {
      var removeItem = $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text();
      console.log(removeItem);
      stringList = $('.removeAddress').map(function(){
        return $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()
      }).get()
      $(this).parent().remove();
      console.log(stringList);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <label>Address *</label>
      <div class="target"></div>
      <input type="text" id="clientAdd" name="address" value="" class="form-control required">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why "try this".  Can you add some info?  Thanks

Comment: @gaetanoM are you refresh the page

Comment: Thanks so much +1

Comment: @prasad thank u for your helpful replay , what if i want to pass the stringList to the input value  of the id="clientAdd" without showing it in the ui  i mean as a variable , so when i click submit it can be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide whole input or you can use input type="hidden". Usually you have one input displayed for humans as a event trigger and input hidden for the value which is processed on the server side

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <label>Address *</label>
              <div class="target"></div>
              <input type="text" id="clientAdd" name="address" value="" class="form-control required">
              <input type="hidden" id="clientAddCode" name="addressCode">
            </div>
          </div>
</div>


var stringList = [];
$("#clientAdd").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which === 13) {
     $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" +"<span class='removeAddress'>"+'+'+"</span>"+ this.value + "</a>");
        stringList.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";
        console.log(stringList);
        $("#clientAddCode").val(stringList);
        $(document).on("click", ".removeAddress", function() {
            var removeItem = $(this).parent().parent().val();
            console.log(removeItem);
            stringList.splice( $.inArray(removeItem, stringList ) ,1 );
            $(this).parent().remove();

            console.log(stringList);
            $("#clientAddCode").val(stringList);
        });
}
});
```